# a lot of books ('a lot of' books or a lot 'of books')

Tags: modifiers, semantics

> a lot of books

In short, 'a lot of'(premodifier) books or a lot 'of books'(postmodifier)?

If premodifier is correct, 'a lot of' is an adjectival phrase that modifies 'books'; if not, 'a lot' is a *kind* of quantity noun that is modified by 'of books'.

Which one is correct analysis either semantically or grammatically or is there any difference in spoken English or written English for this question?

Comment: [A lot] + postmodifier means 'an item or set of items for sale at an auction' so [a lot] of books would be e.g. a truckload of books from a closed library, or someone's collection of Dickens. [A lot of] (premodifier) as you note means 'a large quantity of'. Context and deliberately careful writing and speech avoid any ambiguity.

Comment: You can use "a lot" to mean a large amount without an of-phrase after, e.g. "I bought a lot", "I miss you a lot".

Comment: @StuartF Those are different uses of "lot" . The first NP has ellipsis of the _of_ phrase. NP (in full "a lot of x") functioning as object of "bought". The second NP is a quantificational adjunct modifying the verb "miss".

Answer (score 1):

> *a lot of books*

There is no modifier in this noun phrase.

"Lot" is a non-count quantification noun functioning as **head** of the noun phrase. The determiner "a" simply marks the noun phrase as indefinite.

The preposition phrase "of books" is complement of the head.

Comment: Could you offer a definition of "modifier" that illuminates the distinction between it and "complement"?  Is the difference that of "integral" vs "expendable"?

Comment: No: in NPs complements, unlike modifiers, must be licensed by the head noun (here, "lot"). Additionally, unlike modifiers, complements express semantic arguments of the head noun.

Comment: This would make the parsing of "A lot (in the auction sense) of book"  the same as the parsing of "a lot of (many) books".  Which make me wonder, does meaning have anything to do with syntax?

Comment: Also consider the spoken form "a lotta books"  What is "lotta"?  is it a word (it is surrounded by spaces in the written form).  What word class is "lotta" ?

Comment: @JamesK Even in the auction sense of "lot", the _of_ PP would still be complement of "lot". The syntactic difference is that auction "lot" is a count noun, while quantificational "lot" is non-count.

Comment: @JamesK As far as "lotta" is concerned, I suppose it's best treated as a compound noun which incorporates "of" into the lexical base. I wouldn't put my mortgage money on it though!